# Koin SharedStateViewModel - SavedStateHandle set to null

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel, koin

so in my app, I am using Koin for DI. The app in question is a simple note app and has 2 main fragments: NotesFragment, which shows all notes and InsertNoteFragment, which is used to insert new notes or update existing notes. The InsertNoteFragment has a sharedViewModel, which is shared with BottomSheetDialogFragment, which I use to pick a style for a new note.

Now, when I click a note in NotesFragment, I want to open in in the InsertNoteFragment, so it can be updated. Navigating to the note looks like this:

```
notesAdapter.setOnItemClickListener { note ->
    note.id?.let { id ->
        findNavController().navigate(
             NotesFragmentDirections.actionNotesFragmentToInsertNotesFragment(noteId = id)
        )
    }
```

[image]

When I debug this piece of code, it shows, that the onClick id value corresponds with the note's ID value, so all is good here. The ID value, which I send as a navigation argument, is supposed to be saved in SavedStateHandle which I inject to InsertNoteViewModel (the one, that's shared between InsertNoteFragment and BottomSheetDialogFragment)

```
class InsertNotesViewModel(
private val insertNoteUseCase: InsertNoteUseCase,
private val loadOneItemUseCase: LoadOneItemUseCase,
savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle): ViewModel() {

private val _noteState = MutableStateFlow(Note())
val noteState: StateFlow<Note> = _noteState.asStateFlow()

init {
    println("ID ${savedStateHandle.get<Int>("noteId")}")
    savedStateHandle.get<Int>("noteId")?.let {
        if(it != 0){
            loadOneItem(it)
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel is injected with Koin:

```
viewModel{ params ->
    InsertNotesViewModel(get(), get(), params.get())
}
```

to the InsertNoteFragment and BottomSheetDialogFragment with sharedStateViewModel (as is suggested in Koin Documentation: https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-android/viewmodel/)

```
private val viewModel by sharedStateViewModel<InsertNotesViewModel>()
```

**The problem is** that the SavedStateHandle id value is null every single time. I've tried to not use the lazy delegated injection (using *getSharedStateViewModel()*) but the result is the same. I've been using SavedStateHandle for this purpose before using Hilt and it worked just fine. Any ideas will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to the latest Koin version, see this issue: https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/1386